# MultipleObjectsReturned - get() returned more than one User -- it returned 2

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have some trouble with User.get().
the error msg is:

> MultipleObjectsReturned - get() returned more than one User -- it
> returned 2.

For more explanation here are my **views.py**:

```
def message(request):

    username = request.GET.get('username')

    user = User.objects.get()
    return render(request,'member/message.html',{
        'username':username,
        'user' : user
})

    if User.objects.filter(name=user).exists():

        return redirect('/'+user+'/?username='+username)
    else:
        new_user = User.objects.create(name=user)  
        new_user.save()
        return redirect('/'+user+'/?username='+username) 

def send(request):

    message = request.POST['message']
    username = request.POST['username']
    

    new_message = Message.objects.create(value=message,user=username)
    new_message.save()

    return HttpResponse('Message sent successfully')

def getMessages(request,user):

    user = User.objects.get()
    messages = Message.objects.filter()
    return JsonResponse({"messages":list(messages.values())})
```

and here we have **models.py**:

```
class User(models.Model):
    member_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    confrom_password = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Message(models.Model):

    value = models.CharField(max_length=10000000)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please format your code and include sample data.   How are you getting your responses?  What did you do to get your response?  What is your database like?   Are there more than one entries?  Aren't you supposed to filter the items?  Doesn't ```User.objects.get()``` get all users?

Answer (score 1):

Is the intention of your `getMessages(request, user)` method to get the messages for the given user?

If so, change it to this (you aren't applying filtering since you have no arguments in the `get()` call):

```
def getMessages(request, user):
    user = User.objects.get(username=user)
    messages = Message.objects.filter()
    return JsonResponse({"messages":list(messages.values())})
```

You probably don't need to query User model at all there though as your Message object doesn't have a foreign key to the User table, it's just a CharField so I assume just storing the username.

If you purpose of this method is to just get the messages for your given user then this should work:

```
def getMessages(request, user):
    messages = Message.objects.filter(user=user)
    return JsonResponse({"messages":list(messages.values())})
```

Comment: this process is not working.

Comment: @Dipankar In what way is it not working?

Comment: I just added my User model to this question. It works when there is only one user, it shows error when I add another user.

Comment: did you add the "username=user" bit to your User.objects.get() call?  If so, then you actually do have two users with the same username, which technically your model would support because you have no uniqueness specified in the model.

Comment: This method is not working. I think if you want to change something, you have to change the message cord.